# How to query String list from ParseUser subclass

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I’m trying to get a list of String values (codeName) from a subclass of ParseUser (Player). There are definitely values stored in the database, but I can’t get them in the query list.

```
ParseQuery<Player> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("codeName");       
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Player>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Player> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are  "+ objects.size() + " code names in the database",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    });
```

A list of String values which I can then add to an Arraylist.

New Code

````
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null) {
                        for (ParseUser numbers : objects) {
                            String crawlerF = (String) numbers.get("codeName");
                            databaseCodeNameList.add(crawlerF);
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    ```
But now I can't access the list (dataCodeNameList) outside the ...ParseQuery or another method for some reason...
````

Comment: Is e == null? Also does object.size have a count?

Comment: I understood that your class name is Player, right? So you might want to do `ParseQuery<Player> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Player"); `